# Spark: get groupBy output as list of rows

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

When using group by in spark is it possible to get `Dataset<List<Row>>`

as an output. Here Row is the original row.

```
Dataset<<List<Row>> output = dataset.groupBy("key");
```

If an aggregation is used and the `collect_list` then in the output row, values which are in list format cannot be guaranteed to be in order. Therefore it not a good solution in my case.

Ex: output with aggregation. But order in set values cannot be guaranteed.

```
+-----+----------------------------+
|item1|set                         |
+-----+----------------------------+
|1    |[[5,3], [4,1], [3,2], [2,2]]|
|2    |[[4,1], [1,2], [5,2], [3,1]]|
+-----+----------------------------+
```

Please let know if there is a way to get the output as `Dataset<List<Row>>` without using pojos. (ex for pojo based solution: `FlatMapGroupsWIthStateFunction` )

Comment: I'd even say that it's true _"cannot be guaranteed to be in order"_ in general as for any distributed large dataset problem. What order do you want to apply to your aggregated values? Why don't you use any of the [sort*](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) standard functions?

Answer (score 0):

I have the beginning of a solution for you. You could use `monotonically_increasing_id` to create an index and "remember" the order of the dataframe. Then, you could group by key, aggregate the resultwith `collect_list`, sort the list by the index and finally remove it.

There exists a `sort_array` function to sort array in SparkSQL. Unfortunately, I do not know of any equivalent of the `map` function on a sparkSQL array in order to remove the index. This is why I propose a solution based on a UDF:

```scala
// the UDF that sorts by the index "i" and keeps the value
val sort_and_strip = udf{ (x : WrappedArray[Row]) =>
    x.sortBy(_.getAs[Long]("i"))
     .map(_.getAs[Long]("value"))
}

// an example of use:
spark.range(7)
    .select('id % 3 as "key", 'id as "value")
    .withColumn("i", monotonically_increasing_id)
    .groupBy("key")
    .agg(collect_list(struct('i, 'value)) as "list")
    .withColumn("list", sort_and_strip('list))
    .show(false)
+---+---------+
|key|list     |
+---+---------+
|0  |[0, 3, 6]|
|1  |[1, 4]   |
|2  |[2, 5]   |
+---+---------+
```